# Why 100x100 images form a 10'000-dimension space?

Tags: computer-vision

While reading a paper, I came through that when viewed as vectors of pixel values, face images are extremely high-dimensional. For example, 100x100 images form a 10'000-dimension space. 
How is that possible, I don't seem to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

A vector has only one dimension so if you convert a 2D array into 1D known as Flatten in terms of Neural Networks, the result you'll get would be a vector of 100*100 = 10000 values in one dimension. So, basically, you are accumulating a 2D quantity into 1D.

If you need more info on this topic, you can understand the concept of Flatten from YouTube, it will help you get a pictorial understanding of the concept.

Hope this would help clear your doubt.

Comment: A vector of 10000 values spans a 10000-dimensional space, just like a vector with 3 values spans the 3D space.